# Azure Event Hub firewall does empty settings allow everything to connect

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

I have created event hub namespace to Azure and was wondering how the firewall stuff works for it. Firewall is set as a default to "Selected networks"

[image: Azure Event Hub namespace selected networks]

Should this deny all network traffic to this event hub namespace? If this does not deny all network traffic then what does the "All networks" option do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just ran into this issues yesterday. It appeared that "Selected networks" without any networks populated caused EventHub to deny all traffic.

Edit: After speaking with the team, it seems like this doesn't actually restrict traffic. We were running into an unrelated issue.

Comment: Thanks. it is weird that there is no official MSFT documentation for this. Also even though I have the selected networks selected with empty configuration I can connect to it via my VS code just fine.

Comment: It appears that what I experiences, may have been another unrelated issue.

Comment: It looks that you are working for MSFT so could you use internal resources to confirm this?

Comment: I did. That was the team I spoke with.